# Why does dividend.com say that the VWO ETF has a dividend yield of 5.22%?

Tags: dividends

I see on https://www.dividend.com/dividend-stocks/uncategorized/other/vwo-vanguard-emerging-markets-etf/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191002152655/https://www.dividend.com/dividend-stocks/uncategorized/other/vwo-vanguard-emerging-markets-etf/)):

[image]

[image]

Why does dividend.com say that the VWO ETF have a dividend yield of 5.22%?

When I compute the dividend yield myself using the typical formula

[image]

I get (0.5186 + 0.2792 + 0.0816 + 0.2591)/39.77=**2.8627%** (I compute the Trailing 12 Months (TTM) yield), which is far lower than 5.22%.

https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/VWO/dividends/yield displays a dividend yield similar to the one I computed:

[image]

while displaying on https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/VWO/dividends/history the same dividend history as https://www.dividend.com/dividend-stocks/uncategorized/other/vwo-vanguard-emerging-markets-etf/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191002152655/https://www.dividend.com/dividend-stocks/uncategorized/other/vwo-vanguard-emerging-markets-etf/)):

[image]

https://www.google.com/search?q=vwo also shows a dividend yield of about 2.87%:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that website is averaging across the dividend payments across the lifetime of the stock? There was a split in VWO in 2008-- are they double counting dividends as a result maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears they're taking the *last* dividend payment ($0.5186) divided by the current price ($39.77) and annualizing it:

```
(0.5186 / 39.77) * 4 = 5.22%
```

Although, even their [help page](https://www.dividend.com/dividend-investing-101/dividend-yield/) on dividend yield says *not* to use quarterly dividends:

> The dividend yield is calculated using the annual yield (every regular payout paid that year). It is not calculated by using quarterly, semi annual or monthly payouts.